# List Data Format

Tags: android, sqlite, list, arraylist

I'm fetching Data form Table as list and adding that to sub list but i'm getting output that i didn't expect. I don't know how to Fix that so that i can get the output what i need
    I have attached the code please help me to solve this issue??

```
public List<List<String>> fetchData(){
    List<List<String>> main= new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    List<String> sub= new ArrayList<String>();
    String qry="SELECT * FROM "+myTable+"";
    SQLiteDatabase db= this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(qry, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            System.out.println("-TblPOmaster-");
            sub.add(cursor.getString(0));               
            sub.add(cursor.getString(1));
            sub.add(cursor.getString(2));
            main.add(sub);
            System.out.println("Data:"+main);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());      
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return main;
}

Output what i'm Getting Now


Data:[[a1,a2,a3]]
    Data:[[a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3],[a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3]]
    Data:[[a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3,c1,c2,c3],[a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3,c1,c2,c3],[a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3,c1,c2,c3]]

Output what i need


Data:[[a1,a2,a3]]
    Data:[[a1,a2,a3],[b1,b2,b3]]
    Data:[[a1,a2,a3],[b1,b2,b3],[c1,c2,c3]]
```

Comment: i tried clearing sub.clear(); the data in list sub after adding to main. But then also while adding the data next time it's updating the previous entry as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
      do {
       List<String> sub= new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println("-TblPOmaster-");
        sub.add(cursor.getString(0));               
        sub.add(cursor.getString(1));
        sub.add(cursor.getString(2));
        main.add(sub);
        System.out.println("Data:"+main);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());      
   }
   cursor.close();
   db.close();
return main;
}
```

try to declare sub list inside the cursor and it will work fine